# Fragment not attached to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Hello im trying to start a new login fragment if the condition is true but dont know how the same code was working perfectly fine and im able to get the login fragment when the condition is true from home fragment but after making some changes in login fragment it is showng this error

> if you want more refrence please tell me i will update the question

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Home_Fragment{2138345} (a90215ee-adf7-41d5-97d3-5fd8dd8918fb) not attached to an activity.
```

here is the code i tried to navigate between homefragment to the login fragment

**Home_Fragment.java**

```
public class Home_Fragment extends Fragment {
    public static int saved_position;
    private final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    private final MaterialToolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener toolbarItemClickListener =
            (MenuItem item) -> {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search_button) {
                    new Search_Fragment();
                    getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, Search_Fragment.class, null) // fragment_container is the ID of the fragment holder
                            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                }

                return true;
            };
    public List<Upload> mUploads;
    PostAdapter_Home postsAdapter;
    RecyclerView verticalRecyclerView;
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;
    //firebase
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
//    Boolean isScrolling = false;
//    int currentItems, totalItems, scrolledOutItems;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        MaterialToolbar materialToolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        materialToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(toolbarItemClickListener);
        verticalRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHome);
        shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmerEffect);

//        this is for one item per scroll
        SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(verticalRecyclerView);
        verticalRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);

        verticalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        );
        setupFirebaseAuth();
        getData();
        shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        postsAdapter = new PostAdapter_Home(getContext(), mUploads);
        verticalRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
        verticalRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(Home_Fragment.saved_position);
        return view;
    }


    private void getData() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    verticalRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mUploads.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        assert upload != null;
                        upload.setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        mUploads.add(upload);


                    }

                }

                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }
// ----------------------------------Firebase--------------------------------

    /*
      Setup Firebase Authentication Object
     */

    /**
     * @param user is Logged in
     */
    private void checkCurrentUser(FirebaseUser user) {
        if (user == null) {
            Login_Fragment login_fragment= new Login_Fragment();
            requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, login_fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    private void setupFirebaseAuth() {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = firebaseAuth -> {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            //check if the user is logged in
            checkCurrentUser(user);
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        };
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        checkCurrentUser(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
    }

    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try to replace `requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` with `getParentFragmentManager()` ?

Comment: When are you calling `checkCurrentUser`?

Comment: please check the question i have updated it

Comment: When are you caliing `setupFirebaseAuth()`?

Comment: calling setupFirebaseAuth() in onCreateView

Comment: the logcat shows after you  when checkCurrentUser trigger ?

Comment: ok please check i have updeate the question with entire code also if you want to get refrence of the login fragment // the fragment which i want to start please tell me

Comment: Where is state that before the HomeFragment appear

Comment: when user is not login the first fragment is login fragment and if the user is already loged in ,the first fragment is the home fragment (just as a mention i have only one main activity which handles the bottom navigation and all others are fragments and one xml is is a fragment container) very sorry for the late reply

Comment: when i remove setupFirebaseAuth() method from the onCreateView and also some parameters from the onStart and onStop the app runs perfectly but as obviious  it dosent shows up the login fragment and directly showing me the home fragment when the app starts